# How can I configure my AWS Lambda Python function to target multiple AWS accounts to place a lifecycle policy on any ECR’s that don’t have a LP placed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

Does anyone know how I can configure a function to run on all AWS accounts instead of manually entering an AWS acct ID as a parameter?

Comment: Depends on the trigger, but you're allowed to invoke a lambda from one account based on the event from a resource in another account.

Comment: Your function would need credentials that allow it to access a different AWS Account. This could either be done by 'assuming' an IAM Role in each other account (good method), or by directly providing credentials for each other account (not good method).